# How to use jquery show the title of the image

Tags: jquery

I want to make this: when mouseover on one picture, show its title. I use the below code, when I hover the picture, all the pictures' titles are shown. How do I change the code to make just one title show?

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
        $(function() {
            $('.image').each(function() {
                $(this).hover(
                    function() {
                        $('.title').animate({ opacity: 1 })
                    },
                    function() {
                       $('.title').stop().animate({ opacity: 0});
                   })
                });
        });
</script>

<div class="image"><img src="img1" /><p class="title">text1</p></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img2" /><p class="title">text2</p></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img3" /><p class="title">text3</p></div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try changing this `$('.title')` to `$('.title', this)`

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit rusty on my jQuery, but would this work for you?

```
<script type="text/javascript">       
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $('.image').hover(function()
      {
        $(this).search('p.title:eq(0)').stop().animate({opacity: 1});
      }, function() {
        $(this).search('p.title:eq(0)').stop().animate({opacity: 0});
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div class="image"><img src="img1" /><p class="title">text1</p></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img2" /><p class="title">text2</p></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img3" /><p class="title">text3</p></div>
```

It's because you are calling *all* `.title` elements to animate. You have to find the `.title` element inside of the same `<div>` as the image.

---

Actually, Daniel's answer looks better:

Comment: Right idea but the `.parent()` is wrong. `$(this).find('.title').stop...` is enough. Or `$('.title', this)` as Daniel's answer suggests.

Comment: ... or `$(this).children("p")` for the sake of variety :)